# Difference between dynamic and static type in Dart

Tags: dynamic, dart

Two questions.
First,
Below is strong type.

```dart
String msg = "Hello world.";
msg = "Hello world again.";
```

And, below dynamic

```dart
var msg = "Hello world.";
msg = "Hello world again.";
```

Is there any difference between the two 'msg's above?

Second, if I use 'new' keyword to initiate a variable as below,

```dart
Map myMap = new Map;
```

Why to indicate the variable 'myMap' is a Map instance(Map myMap) as 'new' keyword already include the same meaning? So, isn't it okay just,

```dart
myMap = new Map;
```

Because the 'new' keyword already implies the newly initiated variable is both variable and Map type, I can't understand why normally 'Map' keyword is with the variable name, even 'var' also.

Does anyone have any idea about this (seems a little bit redundant) Dart grammar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regard to the first question, there will be no difference in what each `msg` variable contains.

For the Map question, the reason for specifying the type of a variable that is constructed at declaration is to allow some flexibility with subclasses.  Take for example the following code:

```
class SubMap extends Map {
  SubMap() : super();
}

Map map = new SubMap();
```

Here we have a variable `map` which contains a `SubMap` object as its value, however we are allowing it to contain values of type `Map` (or other types which subclass `Map`) at later times.

The main thing to remember with Dart is that it is optionally typed.  When running your code, none of your type annotiations make any difference at all (unless you run in checked mode). What the type annotations are for is to help your IDE and other tools provide autocomplete help, possible warnings, etc. which other fully dynamic languages like Javascript cannot.

Comment: Wonderful, Now I understand. Thank you @Michael Fenwick

Comment: Note:  Dart 2 does not have checked/unchecked modes (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21066)

Answer (score 3):

```dart
String msg = "Hello world.";
msg = "Hello world again.";
msg = 1; // exception in checked mode - int can not be assigned to String.


var msg = "Hello world.";
msg = "Hello world again.";
msg = 1; // ok in checked mode
```

Checked mode is the developer mode where type annotations are checked and create runtime exceptions when code violates them.

In unchecked (production) mode it makes no difference if you add a type annotation and which one. This is for performance reasons because checked mode is slower.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `Map myMap = new Map()` does three things:

- it declares a variable named `myMap` with type-annotation `Map`,
- it creates a new object using the `Map` constructor, and
- it assigns the object to the variable.

The type annotation means that `myMap` has static type `Map`. The static type can give you some warnings at compile time, but it doesn't change anything at runtime.
The type annotation also adds a type check in checked mode, where any assignment to the variable is checked for being assignable to `Map`.

The object you create could be any object using any constructor. I regularly use `new HashMap()` instead of `new Map()`, and still assign it to a variable typed as `Map`.

Then the object is assigned to the variable, and the type check succeeds, if in checked mode.

The variable is independent of the value used to initialize it. If you later assign a string to the `myMap` variable, it will fail in checked mode.

So, the difference between the two `msg` variables is that one has a static type and a type check in checked mode.
For the code you show, there is no difference in behavior.

If the next line was `var y = msg + 42;`, then the typed version would give a warning (`msg` has static type `String`, and `String.operator+` has type `String->String`, so the `42` has an invalid argument type), where the untyped version wouldn't warn you (`msg` has type `dynamic` so you probably know what you are doing).